# problem deserializing BadRequest response from Web Api using c#

Tags: c#

I have a web api that returns the following json when user registration fails:

```
{
    "$id":"1",
    "Message":"The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
        "$id":"2",
        "": {
            "$id":"3",
            "$values": ["Name username@gmail.com is already taken."]
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried all sorts of things to deserialize it in c# in order to display the error message to the user without any luck.

Here's one on the things I have tried:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/825274/ASP-NET-Web-Api-Unwrapping-HTTP-Error-Results-and?msg=5222750

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please consider adding code to your question that you believe is causing the issue using back ticks `

Comment: The "one of the things I have tried" is not very helpful - its a big article with a lot of code in. If you include in your question the exact code you used that you expect to work with an explanation of what happened when you ran it (eg exception thrown, compile error, etc.) and we will be much better positioned to help you. The article you linked includes code for deserialization which I can only assume works so its really hard for us to say why it hasn't worked for you without seeing what you are actually doing.

Comment: Sorry about that Chris. You are right.  Will try to be more precise in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Define the following class:

```
class WebApiResponse
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, IList<string>> ModelState { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the `Newtonsoft.Json` library to deserialize the json response as an instance of the `WebApiResponse` class:

```
var jsonFromWebApiResponse = @"{""$id"":""1"",""Message"":""The request is invalid."",""ModelState"":{""$id"":""2"","""":{""$id"":""3"",""$values"":[""Name username@gmail.com is already taken.""]}}}";

var webApiResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebApiResponse>(jsonFromWebApiResponse);

foreach (var modelState in webApiResponse.ModelState)
{
    foreach (var innerMessage in modelState.Value)
    {
        // Do something with the messages inside ModelState...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you yv989c, this worked beautifully. Saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem. I developed using vb.net and converted to c#. Not tested on c# but works on vb.net.

```
  class SurroundingClass
{
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var FullResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(WebResult);
        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject lv2 = FullResponse.Item("ModelState");
        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject lv3 = lv2.Item("");
        string DisplayResponse = FullResponse.Item("Message") + " " + lv3.Item("$values").First;

        MessageBox.Show(DisplayResponse);
    }

    public string WebResult()
    {
        return "{'$id':'1','Message':'The request is invalid.','ModelState':{'$id':'2','':{'$id':'3','$values':['Name username@gmail.com is already taken.']}}}";
    }
}
```